# How to process json string as stored procedure parameter

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I need to receive a json string as a parameter of the procedure and parse it as a json object.

An example of this json string: `{'new_settings': [{'setting_name': 'test', 'setting_value': 'test_value'}]}`

I need to fetch the array property named "new_settings" and iterate through the objects inside this array.

This is what i have at the moment:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test` (IN `_settings` longtext)
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE count INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE current_item LONGTEXT;

  START TRANSACTION;
    SET count = (JSON_LENGTH(JSON_EXTRACT(_settings, '$.new_settings')) - 1);

    WHILE i < count DO
      SET current_item := (_settings, CONCAT('$[', i, ']'));

      INSERT INTO settings(setting_name, setting_value) VALUES (JSON_EXTRACT(current_item, '$.setting_name'), JSON_EXTRACT(current_item, '$.setting_value'));

      SET i := i + 1;
    END WHILE;

  COMMIT;
END
```

But i am getting the following error: "Syntax error in JSON text in argument 1 to function 'json_extract' at position 3" and i dont understand what is wrong.

Can you provide some insight?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is all wrong.

You always should check with json Validators, if mysql can read your input.

```
SET @a = '{"new_settings": [{"setting_name": "test", "setting_value": "test_value"}]}';
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(@a, '$.new_settings[0].setting_name') c1
, JSON_EXTRACT(@a, '$.new_settings[0].setting_value') c2;
```

Would give you

```
c1      c2
test    test_value
```

Where did you get your json String?